# New lines dissapear when reading .txt from Android

Tags: c#, string, textbox, multiline

Doing this

```
String t = "asd\nasd";

TextBox objTxt = (TextBox)messageBox;
bjTxt.Text = t;
```

doesnt show

```
asd    
asd
```

as expected, it shows

```
asdasd
```

why, its driving me crazy. TextBox is set to multiline and I can write lines in it manually. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. Still its kind of shitty that I need to do this. I was actually reading a file using ReadToEnd() and now I need to read line by line and use Environment.NewLine at the end of each line.

Answer (score 2):

`TextBox` unlike `Label` and `MessageBox` ignores `"\n"` so if you want to get to the newline you will need to use `"\r\n"` combination. Nevertheless there is a better solution, just use `Environment.NewLine` and you won't need to think about \r\n combination for a newline.

Either:

```
String t = "asd\r\nasd";
```

Or:

```
String t = "asd" + Environment.NewLine + "asd";
```

The beautiful thing about `Environment.NewLine` is that there is no need to worry about the newline in any environment for which you are developing (or at least it should be that way).

**EDIT:**

I saw your comment, so I'll add few words. You could still use `ReadToEnd()` and if the text contains only "\n" for newline, you could do the following:

```
t = t.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

Or:

```
t = t.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

since `Environment.NewLine` is essentially a `string`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Lines` property of `TextBox` to assign all lines from file:

```
textBox.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

And, as I stated in comment above, for your sample you should use `Environment.NewLine` for new line to appear in `TextBox`:

```
textBox.Text = "asd" + Environment.NewLine + "asd";
```